# How to connect two services/apps

Tags: python, computer-science

I have 2 python apps/scripts that i want to be able to communicate with each other and been run from GUI app on demand.

First one generates some simulation file, that is being analysed by 2 app/script. i want the second app/script run after the first one finished.

Also i want the first one to be run after new entry in the db. Do I make an API for both apps to communicate with each other and DB or some messaging like *zeroMQ*.

How to structure services like this.